# ASP.NET 4.0 webform site

Tags: security, jquery-plugins

Is [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) secure from attack? Do I still need to do server side validation? If it's not secure, what kind of attack will it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **always** need to do server-side validation.

Think of client-side validation as pretty, helpful, fast validation for the users' benefit.

Server-side validation is the critical one to have for your database's benefit!

Users may not have JavaScript enabled, in which case the validation can't happen or they could bypass your client-side validation using FireBug etc if they were being malicious about it.

I refer you to little [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).